# Can a doctor watch a women's body?

Tags: sin, medical, human-body, awrah, profession

Asslamo Alaikum, I am Dr. Ahmad. Artificial Intelligence for Medical Researcher. My question is that I am being a medical researcher I am working on breast cancer diagnoser which can detect breast cancer more efficiently than a doctor. Its a life saving work because we all know that breast cancer takes too many lives every year but being a muslim i also have to watch and perform do analysis on thousands of different images of women's body in order to train detecting models and we medical researchers also have to do other researches too which also includes this kinda activity in which we have to see these kind of things anyway. So am i sinning here or its fine. I also want to mention that I am Alhamdulliah happily married and I perform 5/5 daily prayers regularly. I need help from my fellow Muslims to help me regarding this..?